# How does WPF DataGrid get frozen rows/columns working?

Tags: wpf, datagrid, scrollviewer

I created a user control based on Grid (not DataGrid), which is wrapped in a ScrollViewer. Now I would like to have frozen rows/columns capability just like in DataGrid, but couldn't figure out how.

Can somebody give me some insight how it is done in WPF DataGrid?

Comment: What do you mean by frozen? The size?

Comment: Frozen rows/columns like in DataGrid or Excel, so that headers are always visible. More specifically, column headers on top can scroll horizontally, but not vertically; row headers on left can scroll vertically, but not horizontally.

Answer (score 6):

After having this problem by myself I want to share what I've found out so far.

`DataGrid` uses two different methods for that.

---

**First: The RowHeader**

---

This is the simplified `Template` for `DataGridRow`:

```
<Border x:Name="DGR_Border" ... >
    <SelectiveScrollingGrid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGridRowHeader Grid.RowSpan="2"
            SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" ... />

        <DataGridCellsPresenter Grid.Column="1" ... />

        <DataGridDetailsPresenter Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"
            SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}},
                                                                           Path=AreRowDetailsFrozen, Converter={x:Static DataGrid.RowDetailsScrollingConverter},
                                                                           ConverterParameter={x:Static SelectiveScrollingOrientation.Vertical}}" ... />
    </SelectiveScrollingGrid>
</Border>
```

As you can see `DataGrid` uses the [`SelectiveScrollingOrientation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selectivescrollinggrid.selectivescrollingorientation.aspx) attached property to hold the RowHeader in position. If this property is set (or changing) it creates an adapted `TranslateTransform` bound to the parental `ScrollViewer` Offset for the element. See the details in [**source code**](http://daisy-svn.cvsdude.com/tobi/trunk/tobiapp/ExternalLibs/WPFToolkit/DataGrid/Microsoft/Windows/Controls/Primitives/SelectiveScrollingGrid.cs).

---

**Second: The FrozenColumns**

---

This stuff takes place in [`DataGridCellsPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcellspanel.aspx) `ArrangeOverride()`. It uses a private `ArrangeState` class "to maintain state between arrange of multiple children".

```
private class ArrangeState
{
    public ArrangeState()
    {
        FrozenColumnCount = 0;
        ChildHeight = 0.0;
        NextFrozenCellStart = 0.0;
        NextNonFrozenCellStart = 0.0;
        ViewportStartX = 0.0;
        DataGridHorizontalScrollStartX = 0.0;
        OldClippedChild = null;
        NewClippedChild = null;
    }

    public int FrozenColumnCount { get; set; }
    public double ChildHeight { get; set; }
    public double NextFrozenCellStart { get; set; }
    public double NextNonFrozenCellStart { get; set; }
    public double ViewportStartX { get; set; } 
    public double DataGridHorizontalScrollStartX { get; set; }
    public UIElement OldClippedChild { get; set; }
    public UIElement NewClippedChild { get; set; }
}
```

After initializing the state with

```
private void InitializeArrangeState(ArrangeState arrangeState)
{
    DataGrid parentDataGrid = ParentDataGrid;
    double horizontalOffset = parentDataGrid.HorizontalScrollOffset;
    double cellsPanelOffset = parentDataGrid.CellsPanelHorizontalOffset;
    arrangeState.NextFrozenCellStart = horizontalOffset;
    arrangeState.NextNonFrozenCellStart -= cellsPanelOffset;
    arrangeState.ViewportStartX = horizontalOffset - cellsPanelOffset;
    arrangeState.FrozenColumnCount = parentDataGrid.FrozenColumnCount;
}
```

it calls

```
ArrangeChild(children[childIndex] as UIElement, i, arrangeState);
```

for all realized childs and calculates the estimated width for non realized childs/columns.

```
double childSize = GetColumnEstimatedMeasureWidth(column, averageColumnWidth);
arrangeState.NextNonFrozenCellStart += childSize;
```

At the end the values will be set in the appropriate fields in `DataGrid`.

```
private void FinishArrange(ArrangeState arrangeState)
{
    DataGrid parentDataGrid = ParentDataGrid;

    // Update the NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset property of datagrid
    if (parentDataGrid != null)
    {
        parentDataGrid.NonFrozenColumnsViewportHorizontalOffset = arrangeState.DataGridHorizontalScrollStartX;
    }

    // Remove the clip on previous clipped child
    if (arrangeState.OldClippedChild != null)
    {
        arrangeState.OldClippedChild.CoerceValue(ClipProperty);
    }

    // Add the clip on new child to be clipped for the sake of frozen columns.
    _clippedChildForFrozenBehaviour = arrangeState.NewClippedChild;
    if (_clippedChildForFrozenBehaviour != null)
    {
        _clippedChildForFrozenBehaviour.CoerceValue(ClipProperty);
    }
}
```

The details for `ArrangeChild(UIElement child, int displayIndex, ArrangeState arrangeState)` you can find from line 1470 in [**source code**](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGridCellsPanel@cs/1305600/DataGridCellsPanel@cs).

---

**Conclusion**

---

It's not as simple making columns are frozen. Even though this will work (apart from clipping and scrollbar over whole width)

```
<ListView ItemsSource="some rows">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Fixed"
                           Background="LightBlue" Width="300"
                           SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" />
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Scrolled"
                           Background="LightGreen" Width="300" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

this will not:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Fixed"
                   Background="LightBlue" Width="300"
                   SelectiveScrollingGrid.SelectiveScrollingOrientation="Vertical" />
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Scrolled"
                   Background="LightGreen" Width="300" />                    
    </Grid>
</ScrollViewer>
```

The reason is that `DataGridHelper.FindVisualParent<ScrollViewer>(element)` (see from line 149 in [**souce code**](http://reflector.webtropy.com/default.aspx/4@0/4@0/untmp/DEVDIV_TFS/Dev10/Releases/RTMRel/wpf/src/Framework/System/Windows/Controls/DataGridHelper@cs/1305600/DataGridHelper@cs)) in `SelectiveScrollingOrientation attached property` fails. Maybe you find workarounds e.g. create your own attached property with a copy of the original code but get the  `ScrollViewer` by name. Otherwise I think you have to do many things from scratch.

Comment: Okay, I see some clue there, but I couldn't make it work for me. Can you please give me some further hint?

Answer (score 0):

Datagrid Column and Row has a property called "Frozen"

if you want to freeze a column i recommend you do the following

either you want it on selected Row or Column Event and then on the Event Get the Column/Row and mark it as Frozen = true

or create another button or a context menu on mouse right click on which you Freeze/Unfreeze the currently marked

column/row

hope this helps

Comment: This will not help because the question is something else.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Sagar, but that is not what I asked.