# How to achieve scrolling content but static axis (like excel)

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

this is a tough one for me to search and it is easier to illustrate, this is what I want to achieve:

[image]

I have a list (the Y axis) each item in the list contains a list item property (X axis), I want a scrollbar on the content and to keep headers fixed. So far I have tried Items control vertically and the template for each row contains an items control for the horizontal, of course this does not give me static headers but I was going to hack that in with a dummy model or something.

Can anyone tell me what the best way to achieve this is with existing controls. The issue I am having is that it is both dynamic rows and columns.

Here is the current embedded xaml which doesn't achieve what I want:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Items}">
            <ItemsControl.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="ScrollViewer" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.Template>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}"
                                   Width="150" />
                            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Weeks}">
                                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>
                                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <CheckBox Width="30" IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected}"></CheckBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            </ItemsControl>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: if I understand you correctly you are looking for excel like behavior which has fixed row and column headers.

Comment: That is exactly it, I did not think of putting it that way, unfortunately google is still not helping me much so far

Comment: here is an existing solution for frozen rows and columns http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774417/how-does-wpf-datagrid-get-frozen-rows-columns-working, you may adjust the template to get the desired appearance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I attempted a simple solution for you, here is a sample

```
<DataGrid FrozenColumnCount="1"
          HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}"
          VerticalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}"
          RowHeaderWidth="0">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn IsReadOnly="True"
                            Binding="{Binding}" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="1" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="2" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="3" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="4" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="5" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="6" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="7" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="8" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="9" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="10" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="11" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="12" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="13" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="14" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="15" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="16" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="17" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="18" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="19" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="20" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <sys:String>A</sys:String>
    <sys:String>B</sys:String>
    <sys:String>C</sys:String>
    <sys:String>D</sys:String>
    <sys:String>E</sys:String>
    <sys:String>F</sys:String>
    <sys:String>G</sys:String>
    <sys:String>H</sys:String>
    <sys:String>I</sys:String>
    <sys:String>J</sys:String>
    <sys:String>K</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AA</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AB</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AC</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AD</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AE</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AF</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AG</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AH</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AI</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AJ</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AK</sys:String>
</DataGrid>
```

result

[image: result]

if you are ok with a regular datagrid mark on the left top corner here is a solution without frozen columns

```
<DataGrid HorizontalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}"
          VerticalGridLinesBrush="{x:Null}">
    <DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridColumnHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="White" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.ColumnHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRowHeader">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="Content"
                    Value="{Binding}" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowHeaderStyle>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="1" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="2" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="3" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="4" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="5" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="6" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="7" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="8" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="9" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="10" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="11" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="12" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="13" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="14" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="15" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="16" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="17" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="18" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="19" />
        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn Header="20" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
    <sys:String>A</sys:String>
    <sys:String>B</sys:String>
    <sys:String>C</sys:String>
    <sys:String>D</sys:String>
    <sys:String>E</sys:String>
    <sys:String>F</sys:String>
    <sys:String>G</sys:String>
    <sys:String>H</sys:String>
    <sys:String>I</sys:String>
    <sys:String>J</sys:String>
    <sys:String>K</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AA</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AB</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AC</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AD</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AE</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AF</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AG</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AH</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AI</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AJ</sys:String>
    <sys:String>AK</sys:String>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: That's great! I am glad you like it. come back anytime if you feel blocked in such issues. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you may simply be looking for a `DataGrid`?

If not, you probably just need to do a fair bit of development.

Try putting your headers in `ScrollViewer`s and either bind their offset properties to the `ScrollViewer` of the content. You may be unable to simply databind them, so you might need to do this in code behind.

Look at the [`Grid.IsSharedSizeScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid.issharedsizescope(v=vs.110).aspx) property and [`SharedSizeGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.definitionbase.sharedsizegroup(v=vs.110).aspx)s. This might not be so important as all your columns and rows appear to be the same width and height.

Comment: Frozen columns, this was what I was missing to achieve what I would want using a data grid, thank you